# Comparing morphisms of local nature for equivalent topologies

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a scheme. It is known that the smooth topology on $\textrm{Sch}_S$ is equivalent to the étale topology, basically because every smooth covering can be refined to an étale covering.

> **Question**. Is it true, then, that all properties P of morphisms of schemes that are of local nature for the étale topology are also of
>   local nature for the smooth topology?

I believe this would simplify a lot some arguments, which is also why I believe the answer is no... Let me give you one example.

Let P be a property of morphisms of schemes, assumed to be local on the source and target for the étale topology.

**Definition**. A map of Deligne-Mumford $f:\mathcal X\to \mathcal Y$ has P if, given a commutative diagram

$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
X @>{x}>> \mathcal X\\
@V{g}VV @VV{f}V \\
Y @>{y}>> \mathcal Y
\end{CD}$$
where $X,Y$ are schemes and $x,y$ are $\color{red}{\textrm{étale}}$ and surjective, the map $g$ has P.

My question above is equivalent to the following:

**Question'**. Can we replace $\color{red}{\textrm{étale}}$ by $\color{red}{\textrm{smooth}}$ in the above definition?